# Program is finished running dropped off

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

When i run my code i got this

```
-- program is finished running (dropped off bottom) --
```

### This is my code

```
.data
array: .space 12  # Reserve 12 bytes of memory for the array

.text
la $t0, array   # Load the address of the array into $t0

li $v0, 4      # System call code for printing a string
la $a0, prompt # Load the address of the prompt string
syscall         # Print the prompt

.data
prompt: .asciiz "Enter three integers: "

li $v0, 5      # System call code for reading an integer
syscall         # Read the first integer
sw $v0, 0($t0) # Store the first integer in the first word of the array

li $v0, 5      # Read the second integer
syscall
sw $v0, 4($t0) # Store the second integer in the second word of the array

li $v0, 5      # Read the third integer
syscall
sw $v0, 8($t0) # Store the third integer in the third word of the array

lw $t1, 0($t0) # Load the first integer into $t1
lw $t2, 4($t0) # Load the second integer into $t2
lw $t3, 8($t0) # Load the third integer into $t3

add $t4, $t1, $t2 # Add the first two integers and store the result in $t4
add $t4, $t4, $t3 # Add the third integer and store the result in $t4

sw $t4, sum      # Store the sum in memory

.data
sum: .word 0

li $t5, 3      # Load the value 3 into $t5
div $t4, $t5   # Divide the sum by 3 to get the average
mflo $t4       # Store the result of the division in $t4

sw $t4, avg    # Store the average in memory

.data
avg: .word 0

li $t0, 3      # Load the value 3 into $t0
li $t1, 0      # Load the value 0 into $t1

loop:
  lw $t2, 0($t0) # Load the next integer from the array into $t2
  add $t1, $t1, $t2 # Add the current integer to the sum
  addi $t0, $t0, 4 # Move to the next word in the array
  bne $
```

Comment: What do you expect the program to do?

Comment: create an array to store 3 integers , prompt the user to enter three integers , store these integers into memory , calculate the sum and store into memory , calculate the average and store into memory , and use looping mechanism in the code

Comment: Programs have to be programmed to stop gracefully.  Study syscall #10.

Comment: Let me elaborate Erik's comment a bit more. You will only get this error running on a simulator. On a real device, after your last instruction, the CPU will continue running garbage in memory. You have to tell the CPU when to stop running ([look here for syscall 10](https://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html)).

Comment: What does `bne $` mean?